# Who is the original author of the popular cubes pattern?

Tags: patterns, art

I can’t seem to find who the author of this pattern is (though I do find a lot of people selling it on stock sites). I have a friend who always refers to it as an [M. C. Escher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M._C._Escher) pattern, but I’m almost certain that although I also thought at first it was his, I eventually found out [Koloman Moser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koloman_Moser) was the one who authored it. I don’t remember where I got that information, though (or if it was trustworthy or even if I’m recalling it correctly).

Does anyone have a source for it?

[image]

Comment: It's a pattern that likely goes back to ancient times when tiles were 'invented'. I doubt anyone is the sole 'author' of it.

Comment: Very used during the middle age to cover houses or Church floor

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My comment piqued my interest so here’s a bit of research.

One term for this type of pattern is [“diaper pattern”](http://www.house-design-coffee.com/brick-pattern.html):

> In masonry, diaper usually refers to a brick pattern of repeating diamonds.

This example being but one particular diaper pattern.

If you google “diaper tile pattern” you’ll find all sorts of information. I haven’t been able to find any reliable citable sources as to how far back in time it goes, but I’m finding mentions of Rome and Pompeii as well as China. Given the fact that it’s a relatively simple pattern, I’d say it’s quite safe to say it’s at least many thousands of years old. (Part of the challenge of googling this is a combination of a) *baby* diapers and b) The fact that the term ‘roman’ is used extensively in modern marketing of tile products).

Comment: related: 'harlequin tile pattern'